# StackOverflowException during loading the Context from a Compact DB

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

During Setting an `Entity Context` will get a **StackOverflowException**

Database is `SQL Server Compact` with about 220MB and about 200,000 records
as local windows database storage.

It has a NText field

The edmx is generated automatically.

**The Defined Property :**

```
    public static dbEntities Context
    {
        get
        {
            return Context;
        }
        set
        { // The Error locator will stop here as the source of the Error
            Context = value;
        }
    }
```

**Inside the Load Process:**

```
DataStore.Context = new Store.dbEntities() ;
```

Comment: Yes, this will happen. Try see why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just do

```
public static dbEntities Context {get;set;}
```

don't you think that getting or setting Context inside of Context is...well... a little bit recursive ?

Comment: @Sypress see edit : if you need to have a "complete" getter and setter, use private var, not the property itself !

Comment: Yes, :D When when I tried that was just for a test to see what will happen during coding I forgot to change it back, silly mistake !